# emulate file-like behavior in python

Tags: python, sql, file, ftp

I'm writing a script, where I have to dump some columns of tables from an SQL database into a file, and transfer it via FTP.

Because dumps can get really big, my Idea was to write a FakeFile which querys row by row from a cursor in its `readline` method and pass it to `ftplib.FTP.storlines`.

This is what I have so far:

```
import ftplib
import MySQLdb

def MySQLFakeFile(object):
    '''
    Simulates a read-only file, which dumps rows on demand.
    Use this, to pass it to the FTP protocol to make the dump more efficient, 
    without the need to dump it somewhere and copy it over the net afterwords 
    '''
    def __init__(self, cursor, delimeter, table_name, query):
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.delimeter = delimeter
        self.table_name = table_name
        #query is something along select ... FROM %s
        self.cursor.execute(query, table_name)
        self._has_written_index = False
        #file attrs
        self.closed = False
        self.name = table_name + ".csv"
        self.encoding = "utf-8"
        self.mode = "r"


    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.closed = True

    def flush(self):
        '''No-OP'''
        pass

    def read(self, size):
        pass

    def readline(self, size):
        if not self._has_written_index:
            ret = []
            for desc in self.cursor.description:
                ret.append(desc[0])
            self._has_written_index = True
        else:
            ret = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if not ret:
            return None

        s = ""
        for col in ret:
            s += str(col) + self.delimeter
        return s + "\n"

    def readlines(self, size):
        ret = []
        line = self.readline()
        while line:
            ret.append(line)
            line = self.readline()

    def write(self, string):
        raise Exception("cannot write to a MySQLFakeFile")

    def writelines(self, lines)
        raise Exception("cannot write to a MySQLFakeFile")

db = MySQLdb("host", "user", "pass", "db")
ftp = ftplib.FTP("host", "user", "pass")
fakeFile = MySQLFakeFile(db.cursor(), ";", "tableName", "SELECT * FROM %s")
ftp.storlines("STOR tableName.csv", fakeFile)
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 496, in storlines
    if len(buf) > self.maxline:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

What am I doing wrong, and whats the `NoneType` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your readline returns `None` instead of empty string `""` when reached end-of-rows.

Your readlines returns nothing.

```
def readlines(self, size):
    ret = []
    while True:
        line = self.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        ret.append(line)
    return ret
```